# Trying to save data from a mongo query to a variable with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hey guys l have a query and l am trying to save its data into a variable but it keeps on returning undefined everytime l call the variable. The values l am trying to save into to the variable are from the database so l can loop over them with a forEach  loop on a later stage

This is my code:

```
var userData = db.users.find({}, function(err, data){return data})
console.log(userData);
```

l tried to use some of the answers from other posts with people who have encountered the same problem but l am not getting anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @ wscourge, what you refered me to is totaly  the opposite of what l want to so because the answer is using Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Using `async / await` (available since `node -v` == `7.6`):

```
(async function() {

    const userData = await db.users.find({})
    console.log(userData);

})();
```

Using `Promise.then()`

```
db.users.find({})
    .toArray()
    .then(function (userData) { 
       console.log(userData) 
    })
```

Using callback, like you do:

```
db.users.find({}, function(err, data) {

    data.toArray(function(err2, userData) {

         console.log(userData);

    })

})
```